# What is the use of WPF Toolkits?

Tags: wpf, prism, datacontext, wpftoolkit

I recently started working for a small software company and we are developing a small app with WPF, 6 to 10 screens (views?) probably.
The first thing I noticed is that no toolkits are being used. I have little experience with WPF, mainly dealing with existing controls. In my old company they used to work with Prism 'cause it was a big project.

My questions are:

1. Is Prism good for this kind of projects? MVVM Light maybe? Or
   not using toolkits is also good?
2. Right now they set the data context in code behind, which i know
   breaks MVVM, why is that bad?

Comment: you can find more details on http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think you mean MVVM Frameworks instead of Toolkits? Prism is very helpful for big projects, exspecially if you want your application modular. To set the DataContext in CodeBehind is only recommended when u use ViewFirst, but i can recommend MVVM Light, which makes many things easier and more flexible for smaller projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right" way to do it. It really is up to you and the challenges you face/will face with your project.

I've done many apps with frameworks and many without, it all depends on your needs.

Getting used to the various frameworks is a good idea though, so that you can determine when it is beneficial to use them and when it is best to avoid them.

Model View Model Light is a good framework, Caliburn.micro is also very good.

Depending on your UI needs you might also be interested in Mahapps.metro or ModenUI to help *skin* your UI.

If you have the time I would encourage you to experiment with the various frameworks and see what you like/dislike.

For example I wanted to determine if Caliburn.micro and Mahapps.metro would work for a solution I was working on so I set a goal for a small app and gave it a try. I created a [tutorial](http://www.jarloo.com/sojurn-the-tv-app/) of the process, and the code I put up on [GitHub](https://github.com/kelias/Jarloo.Sojurn) in the event someone else was interested.